# не работает ссылка

Tags: html, css

Имею код:

```
<div 
<a href="1.html" 
onmouseover="document.pm1.src='media/21.png'" 
onmouseout="document.pm1.src='media/2.png'"> 
<img src="media/2.png" style="margin-left:1000px;margin-top:150px" border="0" name="pm1" width="150" height="150" alt=""> </a> 
</div>
```

Почему-то не кликается ссылка. Объясните, пожалуйста, почему

Comment: почему у вас `<div` без закрывающей скобки?

Comment: вроде же в конце закрываю

Comment: без скобки, а не без закрыващюего тэга.  у вас `<div` вместо `<div>`

Comment: помогло спасибо

Answer (score 1):

У вас в начале `<div`, а должно быть `<div>`. И уберите атрибуты при наведении на ссылку, вместо этого используйте псевдокласс `:hover` в `CSS` . Так будет правильнее и гибче.